# Sequelize.JS Returning the next earliest entry by date?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

Im running into an problem where I want to query my database using sequelize.js to return, given the createdAt of one instance, the instance with the next earliest createdAt. for example: If I have 3 instances stored in database, created on Monday, Tuesday, and Wednesday. Given the ID or createdAt for the Tuesday instance, I want to return the Monday Instance.
Currently Im pulling all instances and sorting by date, but that is not an efficient solution at all.

This is my first Stack Overflow Question, so i'm not sure if I have the format down for asking questions yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get an instance by ID
2. Select the next earliest instance passing createdAt of the instance:

```
  const { Op } = require('sequelize')
...
  const instance = await await db.yourModel.findById(id)
  const nextEarliestInstance = await db.yourModel.findOne({
    where: {
      createdAt: {
        [Op.lt]: instance.createdAt
      }
    },
    order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']]
  })
```